# Migrating Sybase queries to Oracle Sql : oracle sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, sybase

I have a query written in sybase which gets executed, Anybody knows if there is a easy way to convert this query into Oracle Sql or do we need to manually wrtite this query.

I understand that DML/DDL/procs/views can be migrated using SQL developer.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].

Comment: here is the oracle website that can help..  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/sybase-085571.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We have a T-SQL translator, built right into the SQL Developer UI.

[image]

I talk about it [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/12/sql-developer-give-me-a-google-translator-for-sql/).

If you use the Migration Project to do your translation, when your Sybase object names change, because of size or reserved word limitations in Oracle, the project will know to propagate those name changes throughout your stored procs, views, etc.

This translator is provided for ad-hoc stuff, but it works very well for what it does.